# Syntax issues in update statement

Tags: sql, mariadb

Error message received

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM order_details t1 INNER JOIN orders t2 ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID WHERE t2.O' at line 1

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.QtyShipped = t1.Quantity
FROM order_details t1
INNER JOIN orders AS t2 ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
WHERE t2.OrderStatus = 'Shipped';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try the syntax in query like below

```
UPDATE order_details AS t1
INNER JOIN orders AS t2
ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
SET t1.QtyShipped = t1.Quantity
WHERE t2.OrderStatus = 'Shipped';
```